# FastRWeb performance on Ubuntu with built-in web server

Tags: performance, web-services, r

I have installed FastRWeb 1.1-0 on an installation of R 2.15.2 (Trick or Treat) running on an Ubuntu 10.04 box.  I hope to use the resulting system to run a web service.

I've configured the system by setting http.port to 8181 in rserve.conf and unsetting the socket destination.  I've assigned .http.request to FastRWeb::.http.request.  I exchange JSON blobs between the client and the server using HTTP POST (the second blob can exceed 150KB in size, and will not fit in an HTTP GET query string.)

Everything works end to end -- I have a little client-side R script which generates JSON RPC calls across the channel.  I see the run function invoked, and see it returned.

I've run into a significant performance problem, however: the return path takes in excess of 12 seconds from the time run() returns (including the call to done()) and the time that the R client gets the return value.  RCurl doesn't seem to be the culprit; it appears that something is taking twelve seconds to do a return.

Does anybody have any suggestions of where to look?  I can easily shift over to using Apache 2.0 and CGI, but, honestly, I'd rather keep everything R centric.

Comment: Can you provide the little client-side script?

Comment: To first order, here's the script:

`postForm('http://jwlm.example.com:8181', 
          first.json=first.json,
          second.json=curlEscape(big.json.blob),
          style='post')`

The two json blobs are about 2.5KB and about 150KB, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

I wrapped .http.request with an Rprof()/Rprof(NULL) pair and looked at the time spent in each routine.  It turns out that the system spends ~11 seconds inside URLDecode in the standard implementation of .run.  This looks like a scaling problem in URLDecode in the core.